# Google Sheets setRowHeight() auto-fitting, NOT resizing to set value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a Google form/sheet which collects data creating cells that are so large that navigating up and down rows becomes tricky.

The below function should resize all rows (except the header row 1) to 50.
However, when it runs, all rows Auto-fit the data, again making it again unwieldy.

```
var sheetResponses = 'Form responses 3';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var responsesSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetResponses);
var responseData = responsesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// Sets all rows to a height of 50
function resizeRowsTo50() {
  responsesSheet.setRowHeights(2,responseData.length,50);
};
```

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong? Even if I manually resize all of the rows to a uniform height beforehand, the function reverts them back to fit the data.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: [Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nEFVRa2Db8SsQhGpc6dkgKHQIgAM6pS83swBRq6QFV0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've run your code several times, as-is and with some mods - same result every time: no problems, changes the row height to 50 and nothing more. I wonder whether you have a local setting for Text Wrapping (Format>Text Wrapping) that is interfering with the results. I started with a blank sheet and my Text Wrapping is set to "overflow". Only other suggestion is to share your sheet so that I can see the Auto-Fit phenomena first hand.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me. I just tried it with all 3 Text Wrapping settings and it's still auto-fitting rather than resizing to 50. Unfortunately I cant share the sheet as it's confidential but if I can replicate the problem with some dummy data, I'll link it here. I'll stick with manually resizing for now.

Comment: Yep, that is worthwhile. May I suggest that you make a copy of your original sheet in order to build the dummy; if it is a setting then best to be working on the original settings rather than a clean sheet.

Comment: I've added a link to the dummy sheet showing the same behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It appears that `setWrap` and `setWraps` override any manual or
>   programmed (`setRowHeight`/`setRowHeights`) row height adjustment.

The documentation for `setWrap` and `setWraps` says "**Cells with wrap enabled (the default) resize to display their full content**" (*emphasis is mine*). That is, the cell width remains unchanged, and the row height changes to enable display of the entire content.

It goes on... "Cells with wrap disabled display as much as possible in the cell without resizing or running to multiple lines". In the later case, the amount of text displayed otherwise depends on the width of the column.

By comparison, when the settings are adjusted manually (the row height set to 50 pixels and text wrapping set to wrap), the row does **not** revert to auto-fit.

I've re-run my initial tests and I believe that I may misinterpreted your auto-fit comments when comparing my results. My apologies.

The auto-fit outcome appears deliberate on Google's part - even though the effect is very different to the effect of the manual "Wrap" adjustment. These are relatively new commands (at the time of writing) and there are very few examples to be found online.

I've raised this as a [feature issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121054553) and we'll see whether that generates any clarification and/or change.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this, and no need for apologies! This sounds like a good description of what's happening so I'll be interested to see there is a response to the issue tracker. I've accepted this explanation as an answer as it seems that there is not currently a working resolution.

Comment: [`setRowHeightsForced()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsforcedstartrow,-numrows,-height) is available now.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Omegastripes, now there is another method .setRowHeightsFrorced(). So you should modify your code as below:

```
var sheetResponses = 'Form responses 3';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var responsesSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetResponses);
var responseData = responsesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// Sets all rows to a height of 50
function resizeRowsTo50() {
  responsesSheet.setRowHeightsForced(2,responseData.length,50);
};
```

**Reference:** [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsforcedstartrow,-numrows,-height)

Answer (score 0):

I found a poor decision for me in this tricky way:
- set Wrap to text wrapping;
- set setRowHeight;
- cut the string to such symbols amount which is enough for setted Row Height.
(but you still can see "fit to data" when you trying to resize your row)
I mean I fit my data to my rows hight before google sheet fit hight to my data:)