# Google Sheets / Apps Script - SetRowHeight with text inside cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Just discovered that I cannot set the height of a given row with a height value lower than the text height inside a cell.

sheet.setRowHeight(1, 5) is working if cell is empty but not working if text (eg font size 8) is inside. It seems the cell is resized to the text height.

Is it possible to override it (especially because a padding seems applied on top and bottom of the text) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets setRowHeight() auto-fitting, NOT resizing to set value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430183/google-sheets-setrowheight-auto-fitting-not-resizing-to-set-value)

Comment: I also found this one, but did not get into details because do not use setWrap methods. Nevertheless, it seems that this strange behaviour(fit to text size instead of row height specified in setRowHeight) applies whatever the wrap methodology used!

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the row height by ignoring the font size using Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, when `setRowHeight` of Spreadsheet service is used, it seems that the minimum row height depends on the font size. So in this case, as the workaround, I would like to propose to use Sheets API. In this workaround, `UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest` of the method of "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" in Sheets API is used.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  // Please set the sheet name.

  const requests = {updateDimensionProperties: {
    properties: {pixelSize: 5},
    range: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), startIndex: 1, endIndex: 2, dimension: "ROWS"},
    fields: "pixelSize"
  }};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this sample script, the row height of the row 2 is changed to 5 pixels. In this case, the row height doesn't depend on the font size.

#### References:

- [setRowHeight(rowPosition, height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightrowposition,-height)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)